# Configure authentication - Google Analytics Data API (GA4) in PHP

Tags: php, bash, environment-variables, google-analytics-api, google-analytics-4

I'm trying to locally authenticate the Google Data API for GA4.
On this document in Step 3: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/data/v1/quickstart-client-libraries the info shared is to set the application credentials in the example. ***Thanks to @ADyson this has been confirmed as working as expected.***

**NEW ISSUE:**

When using Terminal to test my php file in the command line it shows the executed code working as expected, eg:
`a@Ds-Mac-mini ~ % php /Users/a/Documents/projects/sample.php Report result:  (not set) 243 New York 114 Melbourne 40`

Now when trying to run the same file in my browser (already enabled `php -S localhost:8080`) it comes back with an error.

`Fatal error: Uncaught Google\ApiCore\ApiException: { "reason": "ACCESS_TOKEN_SCOPE_INSUFFICIENT", "domain": "googleapis.com", "errorInfoMetadata": { "service": "analyticsdata.googleapis.com", "method": "google.analytics.data.v1beta.BetaAnalyticsData.RunReport" }, "message": "Request had insufficient authentication scopes.", "code": 7, "status": "PERMISSION_DENIED", "details": [ { "@type": "type.googleapis.com\/google.rpc.ErrorInfo", "reason": "ACCESS_TOKEN_SCOPE_INSUFFICIENT", "domain": "googleapis.com", "metadata": { "service": "analyticsdata.googleapis.com", "method": "google.analytics.data.v1beta.BetaAnalyticsData.RunReport" } } ] } thrown in /Users/a/Documents/projects/vendor/google/gax/src/ApiException.php on line 267`

Not sure why it's working in Terminal and not localhost:8080

**CODE BEING USED IN SAMPLE.PHP**

```
<?php

// Report all PHP errors
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');

require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';

use Google\Analytics\Data\V1beta\BetaAnalyticsDataClient;
use Google\Analytics\Data\V1beta\DateRange;
use Google\Analytics\Data\V1beta\Dimension;
use Google\Analytics\Data\V1beta\Metric;

/**
 * TODO(developer): Replace this variable with your Google Analytics 4
 *   property ID before running the sample.
 */
$property_id = '3XXXXXXX3';

$client = new BetaAnalyticsDataClient();

// Make an API call.
$response = $client->runReport([
    'property' => 'properties/' . $property_id, 
    'dateRanges' => [
    new DateRange([
    'start_date' => '2023-03-31',
    'end_date' => 'today',]),
    ],
    'dimensions' => [new Dimension(
    ['name' => 'city',]),
    ],
    'metrics' => [new Metric(
    ['name' => 'activeUsers',])
    ]
]);

// Print results of an API call.
print 'Report result: ' . PHP_EOL;

foreach ($response->getRows() as $row) {
    print $row->getDimensionValues()[0]->getValue()
    . ' ' . $row->getMetricValues()[0]->getValue() . PHP_EOL;
}

?>
```

Comment: Do you expect an output from the `export` command? If so, why? Check the [manual](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/export.1p.html). See also https://www.serverlab.ca/tutorials/linux/administration-linux/how-to-set-environment-variables-in-linux/ - you can test if the environment variable was set correctly or not by running `echo $GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` on the next terminal line.

Comment: Thanks @ADyson - I'm new to this so would have assumed an error message of some sort. All good. Running the code you shared it is pointing to the right file.
The problem now looks to be trying to run it not from Terminal but on localhost:8080 where it comes back with:

"message": "Request had insufficient authentication scopes.",
    "code": 7,
    "status": "PERMISSION_DENIED",
    "details"

Comment: Show also the command which produces the error message, and post the exact error message.

Comment: Hi @user1934428 - error comes back with:
`"message": "Request had insufficient authentication scopes.",
"code": 7,
"status": "PERMISSION_DENIED",
"details": [{
  "@type": "type.googleapis.com\/google.rpc.ErrorInfo",
  "reason": "ACCESS_TOKEN_SCOPE_INSUFFICIENT",
  "domain": "googleapis.com",
  "metadata": {
    "service": "analyticsdata.googleapis.com",
    "method": "google.analytics.data.v1beta.BetaAnalyticsData.RunReport"
thrown in /Users/a/Documents/projects/vendor/google/gax/src/ApiException.php on line 267`

Comment: Please [edit] your post with important info like this, and also a [mre] of the issue. Code and errors don't belong buried in the comments and it seems now that actually the environment variable is probably not the issue

Comment: Please edit your question and include your code.  Not a link to the docs we need to test what you are running.   what exactly is in sample.php

Comment: Thanks @LindaLawton-DaImTo - I've updated the description with a copy of the sample.php file

Comment: Can i get you to try and supply the key file directly rather than relying on the env var?   $client = new BetaAnalyticsDataClient([
        'credentials' => $service_account_key_file_path
    ]);    Let me know what happends

Comment: Thanks @LindaLawton-DaImTo - Adding that piece of code worked a treat when viewing the request via the browser!
Would there be a way to reference this file without sharing the direct path, for obvious security reasons, and to be used once for any subsequent requests the user would make? ie. user goes to a different page in a dashboard and doesn't need to have it authenticated again

Comment: Check my answer.   Its a service account it doesn't matter if it needs to authencation again just let it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you feed it the credentials file directly it may be able to access it.

```
BetaAnalyticsDataClient([ 'credentials' => $service_account_key_file_path ]);
```

My guess is that either it cant see GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS or the path leading to GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS is not one that it can reach.

If the first option works i would look into why it cant find GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS